# react native Webview Process Terminated

Tags: react-native, webview

Im using react native to show a local HTML on a web view,
I have noticed that some times randomly, the webView crashes, and I get the message on console:

```
Webview Process Terminated
```

I have searched about it, but cannot find any answers?
what is that? why is happening? how to avoid it or reload web view after that error?

```
 <WebView
      style={styles.webContainer}
      originWhitelist={['*']}
      source={isAndroid ? {uri:'file:///android_asset/binaura.html'} : HTML_FILE}

      javaScriptEnabled={true}
          domStorageEnabled={true}

    />
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If by "WebView" you mean `react-native-webview`:

This happens on **iOS** if the WebView is using too many resources, and results in either the WebView crashing (showing a blank white page) or the app freezing.

There is a callback property, `onContentProcessDidTerminate` (introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview/pull/774)), that you can use to listen for termination and force a reload of the WebView by updating its key. It's a bit of a hack, but it works.

Usage example:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    webviewKey: 0,
  }

  reload() {
    this.setState({
      webviewKey: this.state.webviewKey + 1,
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        key={this.state.webviewKey}
        onContentProcessDidTerminate={this.reload}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

@pjivers answer put us on the right track but the current react-native-webview already has a `reload()` method you can use. You only need a bit of ref setup to call it:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.webViewRef = React.createRef();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <WebView
        ref={this.webViewRef}
        onContentProcessDidTerminate={this.webViewRef.current?.reload}
      />
    )
  }
}
```